# Lync 2010 Group Chat Logging

Tags: windows, powershell, lync, instant-messaging

My group is rolling out Lync 2010 Group Chat and it seems from the documentation that the Lync Server does not log actual conversation history for Group Chat. I find this suspect because if conversation history is enabled in a given chat channel, even on log out, the history remains for the room. I have not been able to find where the channel history is stored however.

Is that information written to the back end MSSQL Database? And if so, is there a way to get it out into a .txt or similarly readable format? (I have almost no experience with SQL Databases!)

I was also wondering if anyone knew if the Archiving server role for Lync Server would also archive messages in Group Chat like it does with Lync? Lync and Group Chat are two separate clients but they run on the same server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft's [TechNet article about it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg425863.aspx), you'll want to enable a feature called 'Compliance' for your Group Chats. This will have it keep a record of all group chat related things. The article doesn't make it clear whether or not an Archiving server is required for that specific functionality, but it does say if you want to be able to retain individual IM messages, you DO need an Archiving server.

There's another feature of Group Chat, called Persistence, which is described as: "Group Chat feature that enables Group Chat content to be retained after the end of a Group Chat session and accessed on an ongoing basis."

I think between those two features you should be able to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: I was aware of the Persistence feature, which lead me to believe that the information was stored somewhere so that it could be pulled again for a persistent history in a chat channel. Compliance looks like exactly what i'm looking for though. Thanks for the information. I will test it out and report back for future reference.

Comment: No problem, let me know how it pans out and if you find further questions along the way, I'll do my best to help fill in the blanks!

Comment: Another questions for you, if I may. I am configuring a test environment of Lync Server 2010 since the current one is in production. I am running into an issue with the Topology Builder. I have the SQL Store, and the File Share on the same server as the Lync Server installation. The Topology Builder will not let me use the correct FQDN for the File and SQL stores because "FQDN is already in use in this Topology" Am I forced to use ANOTHER server for the SQL installation, and yet ANOTHER for the File Share?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I hadn't signed in for a few days. Let me do a little research, and I'll get back to you on this follow-up question.

Comment: @emhohensee What kind of install are you doing? Standard, or Enterprise?